# Compiling iPhone app with Xcode makes the phone die

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a program that I have compiled to an iPhone 5 a number of times but suddenly after I recompiled after some changes to the program the iPhone goes completely dead.
I have tried pressing the On button for more than 30 seconds with and without also pressing the Home button but it is dead.
Does anyone know of this happening before and are there any advice how to get the phone back to life again?

Edit2: Yes the Phone is black screen and don't react to pressing any buttons.

Edit: With recompile I only mean compiling again. Regarding the pressing On and Home button I mean on the real (dead) device to try to wake it up / Reboot it. The phone is plugged into the charger and is fully loaded. Since the phone is dead it is not possible to delete the app. Regarding code samples I have used my New Ipad after the phone died so the code is not the exactly same as when the phone problem occurred. There are more VCs in the Project but it was when editing this part the problem occurred. 
I think I might have forgot the + signs between the two last strings in the mailMessage2 composition if you think this may be a cause.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MessageUI

var mailSubject = String()
var mailMessage1 = String()
var mailMessage2 = String()
var mailMessage3 = String()
var mailMessage4 = String()

class KundData: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tfKundNamn: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tfKontaktPerson: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tfKundNummer: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tfTelefon: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tfEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tfSlutkund: UITextField!

    var salesPersons = ["Sales engineer", "PersonA", "PersonB", "PersonC", "PersonD", "PersonE", "PersonF"]
    @IBOutlet weak var salesPerson: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var salesIndex: UIStepper!

    @IBAction func salesStepper(sender: UIStepper) {
        salesPerson.text = salesPersons[Int(sender.value)]
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.salesIndex.wraps = true
        self.salesIndex.autorepeat = true
        self.salesIndex.maximumValue = Double(salesPersons.count - 1)

        var value = Int(self.salesIndex.value)
        self.salesPerson.text = salesPersons[value]
    }

    // Gör att keyboardet försvinner när man pekar nånstans i vyn som inte är views
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBAction func sendEmailButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
        }
    }

    func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property

        mailSubject = "Förfrågan från \(tfKundNamn.text), \(tfKontaktPerson.text)"
        mailMessage1 = "Kund: \(tfKundNamn.text)\n" +
        "Kundnummer: \(tfKundNummer.text)\n" +
        "Kontaktperson: \(tfKontaktPerson.text)\n"

        mailMessage2 = "Telefon: \(tfTelefon.text)\n" +
        "Email: \(tfEmail.text)\n" +
        "Slutkund: \(tfSlutkund.text)\n" +
        "Försäljare: \(salesPerson.text)\n"

        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["kim.jerkhagen@flexlink.com"])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject(mailSubject)
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(mailMessage1 + mailMessage2 + mailMessage3 + mailMessage4, isHTML: false)

        return mailComposerVC
    }

    func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
        let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        sendMailErrorAlert.show()
    }

    // MARK: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate Method
    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!) {
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Comment: What is for you compile/recompile?? And also, press the home button? Do you mean the physical device of the phone? That actin is independent of your aplication... Please add more  information, you will have more sucess in been help.

Comment: Is the phone plugged in/charged?

Comment: Try deleting the app from your phone and cleaning the build. If that doesn't help, try setting an exception breakpoint and see if it gets triggered

Comment: Can you provide some code samples, please?

Comment: Sometimes compiling apps it hangs up device, you just need to disconnect the device from system & restart iPhone.

Comment: is it your iPhone shows black screen? iPhone is not started even you press the start button?

Answer (score 0):

If your iPhone is dead, you can follow these steps
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKFFFe0r-T4